# root account in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I had installed ubuntu 10.04.

A user account has been created under my name.

But no question has been asked of root account.

So, I was wondering how to login under root account.

Kindly provide some suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu is secure because of that very feature. The `root` account is *very* dangerous to use. If you make a file with that account, only `root` can delete it. The trash can fills up, but you can't empty it. It's a pain, so don't do it.

You are probably needing to do something with elevated privileges. The command `sudo` lets you do just that.

It lets you run individual commands as `root`, without being root. It's quite simple to use:

```
sudo do --stuff=here
```

And you will be prompted for a password (your password, not root's).

Comment: Although I agree that sudo is a better approach, I think the first paragraph is alarmist . There's some good information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo) regarding the potential downside of logging in as root.

Comment: Those are basically all the problems I've ever had with `root ;)

Comment: It's an odd list of the dangers of root.  The primary risk of logging in as root is that you accidentally make significant and unintended changes to the system (very possibly without noticing).

Answer (score 1):

Typically, people are happy with `sudo(8)` access to system administrator commands. I personally love `sudo -s`.

But if you must enable direct logins to root, [Ubuntu has provided instructions you can follow](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo).

Answer (score 1):

One of the things i do not like from ubuntu is this thing.

In order to "create" a root account, you can do

```
sudo passwd
```

Then you will type a password, after that you can always use

```
su
```

In order to login as root, and of course, sudo is still there anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to login as `root`

Instead you use `sudo` to perform those tasks.

It will ask for *your* password.

Answer (score 0):

In ubuntu, you use your user account instead. Use:

```
sudo "what you want to do"
```

In a terminal to perform a task with elevated rights.

If you specifically want to log on as root, use:

```
sudo su
```

Comment: Actually I believe `sudo -i` is the preferred way of getting a root prompt.